# Can't import Spring Cloud dependencies for enabling Eureka client

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

[image]I work on app in which I try to register Eureka client on server but stuck on the first step where I need dependency which make enable @EnableEurekaClient annotation.

1. I followed cloud.spring.io instructions which did not work:

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ```

II) I then found some latest stack & tried (as follows) which did not work as well:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

I wonder, as all folder suddenly disappear in case I put above dependency in the pom.xml (I use Intellij)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.eurekaproject.learn</groupId>
<artifactId>microservice-app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>microservice-app</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: microservice-app
datasource:
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/microservice-app
username: root
password: 12345
jpa:
hibernate:
  ddl-auto: none

server:
 port: 8092

eureka:
  client:
   service-url:
    defaultZone: http://localhost:8081/eureka

info:
 app:
   name: ${spring.application.name}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Spring Cloud BOM to your `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2020.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Once this is added, all Spring Cloud dependencies including `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` will resolve, and you should be able to use annotations such as [@EnableDiscoveryClient](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/main/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EnableEurekaClient.java) for activating the Eureka discovery client.

Comment: It seems work but bring no dependency I attach screen fyi.

Comment: Please note that the `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` dependency must be specified *outside* the `dependencyManagement` section. Just add `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` along with your other dependencies.